# gnuplot arbitrary labeling x - axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data file for gnuplot

```
1 0.5 0.9
2 -0.1 0.5
3 0.7 0.4
```

where the first column is x-axis, and 2,3 columns are two different graphs.
Coordinates of x-axis are always natural numbers, they represent the location of the word in sentence, 2 and 3 columns is just the result of function on the word in sentence.

I wonder if it's possible to label "1", "2" ,... on the x-axis with words from sentence.

If I would have

```
1 A 0.5 0.9
2 green -0.1 0.5
3 apple 0.7 0.4
```

ans then in stead of 1,2,3 I would have "A" "green" "apple".

Please let me know if it's possible to do with gnuplot.

Answer (score 6):

Use `xticlabels` to select a column for your custom labels:

```
plot 'file' using 1:3:xticlabels(2)
```