# gnuplot: change value of x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have the followig file (frequency.txt) in which I store the frequency of letters from a file:

```
a  1619     1029 
c  1023     299 
b  208      55 
e  2238     694 
d  737      128 
g  230      42 
f  191      93 
i  2064     716 
h  91       8
```

I want to make a plot with these values but I want the letters which appear in the first column of the file to represent the values which appear on the x-axis in the plot. I tried changing the `xtics` like so:

```
set xtics ('a' 1,'c' 2,'b' 3,'e' 4,'d' 5,'g' 6,'f' 7,'i' 8, 'h' 9)
```

But that seems tedious and I am sure that there must be a better way to do this.

Here is the whole code for making the graph:

```
set size 1.0 , 0.6
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color dashed lw 1 "Helvetica" 14
set output "comparison_percentages.eps"
set autoscale
set xtics ('a' 1,'c' 2,'b' 3,'e' 4,'d' 5,'g' 6,'f' 7,'i' 8, 'h' 9) set ytic auto
set boxwidth 10
set xlabel "Letters"
set ylabel "Percentages"
plot "frequency.txt" using 1:2 with lines t "Website", \
"frequency.txt" using 1:3 with lines t "Python"
```

How can I change the code such that it will also read the first column from the file and use the letters for the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task you can use the `xticlabels` command in the `using` statement (see also the very recent question [gnuplot arbitrary labeling x - axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821701/gnuplot-arbitrary-labeling-x-axis)):

```
set xlabel "Letters"
set ylabel "Percentages"
set style data lines
plot "frequency.txt" using 2:xticlabels(1) t "Website", \
     "" using 3 t "Python"
```

with the result (using 4.6.5):

[image]